# How to change the response body in side of AbstractGatewayFilterFactory - Spring Cloud Api Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, api-gateway

My goal is to check every inbound query for Authorization token and redirect it to another URL with understandable description if the check fails (i.e. HTTP 401: "There is no auth token in the query"). I'm using *AbstractGatewayFilterFactory* for this.

Here is two approaches I tried. Please, take a look on it and let me know what I did wrong or maybe advice your own approach, if suits better for my goal.

**1. First approach: mutate the request.**

The problem here: it being redirected to correct PATH, but incorrect HOST.

- For instance, original request was to:
  *"http:USERSERVICE/users/tasks"*,
- I want to redirect it to *"http:APIGW:8080/apigw/askauth"*
- But finally its being redirected to *"http:USERSERVICE/apigw/askauth"*
  : so it's a kind of hybrid of two URLs, which ignores the HOST I want
  to redirect to and uses only relative path.

The code is here:

```
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<UserAuthenticationFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            try { //...some code here for check the Token...
            
            } catch (TokenNotFoundException e) {

                URI redirectUri = URI.create("http:127.0.0.1:8080/apigw/askauth");

                ServerHttpRequest request = exchange
                        .getRequest()
                        .mutate()
                        .uri(redirectUri)
                        .method(HttpMethod.GET)
                        .build();

                ServerWebExchange mutatedExchange = exchange
                        .mutate()
                        .request(request)
                        .build();

                mutatedExchange.getAttributes().put(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, request.getURI());

                return chain.filter(mutatedExchange);
            }       

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        };
    };
```

**2. Second approach: change Response to HTTP 401.**

It works fine, but I can't set the readable message, because ServerHttpResponse response don't have such option.So i'm just giving 401 ERROR without readable description, which is not good at all.

```
@Component
public class UserAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<UserAuthenticationFilter.Config> {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {

        return (exchange, chain) -> {

            try { //...some code here for check the Token...            
                
                } catch (TokenNotFoundException e) {
               
               ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
               response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
               return response.setComplete();
            }       

        return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(request).build());
        };
    };
```

Comment: providing helpful error messages in security related responses is very bad practice and aids hackers in their shenanigans.

Comment: also using JWT tokens as sessions is also bad practice, and that is why there is no built in filter for that in spring security. So why are you building insecure applications?

Comment: So whats is a good practice then?

Comment: dont give helpfull error messages in 401 and 403 responses, and use traditional cookie sessions, by for instance implementing `FormLogin` as described in the spring security documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Chek this

```java
....
exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
byte[] yourObjects;
try {
    Map<String, String> data=new HashMap<>();
    data.put("name","Mafei");
    yourObjects = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsBytes(data);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
return exchange.getResponse()
        .writeWith(Mono.just(exchange.getResponse()
        .bufferFactory().wrap(yourObjects)));
```

But providing advice to the hackers through the message is not recommended